# Packages for standard solar system (astronomical) symbols

Tags: symbols, packages

I want to get this specific set of symbols through some latex packages.

[image]
Photo source: https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/680/solar-system-symbols/

I have tried using the packages `mathabx` and `wasysym`.

The package `mathabx` gives my desired earth symbol and the symbols font is scaled properly when I am using them as subscripts. But I don't like its Saturn symbol. Also, it's giving some error messages by interacting with the other important packages such as `amsfont`, `amsmath` etc.

On the other hand, the package `wasysym` doesn't give my desired earth symbol, and the symbols font isn't scaled properly when I am using them as subscripts.
My issue can be understood by running this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}  % Default class for composing an article
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{physics}   
\usepackage{wasysym} 

\newcommand{\e}{\earth}
\newcommand{\sa}{\saturn}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \text{Using mathabx : }& \nonumber \\
    & \Saturn : g_\Saturn, \quad \Earth : g_\Earth \\
        \text{Using wasysym : }& \nonumber \\
        & \saturn : g_{\saturn}, \quad \earth : g_{\earth} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \text{Using mathabx : }& \nonumber \\
    &\frac{\Delta m_\Saturn}{m-m_\Earth} = \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{\Delta v_\Saturn}{I_{\text{sp}}g_\Earth}} \right) \label{del m_A}  \\
        \text{Using wasysym : }& \nonumber \\
        & \frac{\Delta m_{\saturn}}{m-m_{\earth}} = \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{\Delta v_{\saturn}}{I_{\text{sp}}g_{\earth}}} \right) \label{del m_A} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

How can I generate the desired symbols as given in the photo and also with proper font scaling (while using as subscript/superscript)? Are there any other dedicated/updated packages available for these symbols?

Comment: It is possible to use mathabx glyphs without loading the package. Of course, this does not solve the problem of your disliking Saturn.

Comment: You can also use them from Unicode.

Comment: Does the [astro](https://ctan.org/pkg/astro) package work for you?

Comment: @usernumber, no I haven't tried the astro package.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, since I like some mathabx symbols but I prefer do not load the package; can you provide and example how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option using the [starfont](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/starfont) package. Math versions of the symbols are declared separately to provide proper scaling in sub/superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    starfontserif % comment for sans glyphs
    ]{starfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{starfontsym}{OT1}{sts}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathSun}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{115}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathMercury}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{102}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathVenus}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{103}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathTerra}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{76}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathvarTerra}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{108}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathMoon}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{100}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathvarMoon}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{97}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathMars}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{104}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathJupiter}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{106}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathSaturn}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{83}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathUranus}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{70}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathvarUranus}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{65}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathNeptune}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{71}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathPluto}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{74}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathvarPluto}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{72}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rcc}
Sun & \Sun \\
Mercury & \Mercury \\
Venus & \Venus \\
Earth & \Terra & \varTerra \\
Moon & \Moon & \varMoon \\
Mars & \Mars \\
Jupiter & \Jupiter \\
Saturn & \Saturn \\
Uranus & \Uranus & \varUranus \\
Neptune & \Neptune \\
Pluto & \Pluto & \varPluto
\end{tabular}

\begin{align}
    & \mathSaturn : g_\mathSaturn, \quad \mathTerra : g_\mathTerra
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    &\frac{\Delta m_\mathSaturn}{m-m_\mathTerra} = \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{\Delta v_\mathSaturn}{I_{\mathrm{sp}}g_\mathTerra}} \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: syms]

You can figure out the numbers used in `\DeclareMathSymbol` by looking at the corresponding definitions in `starfont.sty`.