# How to extract only astronomical symbols from `mathabx` package?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, symbols, mathabx

By analyzing my document I noticed that the less or equal symbol `leq` is printed in undesiderate way becuase the `mathabx` package overwrites other mathematical packages. I need to extract only astronomical symbols from `mathabx` package (see following screenshot taken from the package documentation):
[image: astrosymbols_from_mathabx]

Here is my MWE where I noticed the different symbols (slant equal sign instead of horizontal) produced by `leq` if the `mathabx` package is active:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathabx} % enable astronomy symbols


\begin{document}

$\leq$

\end{document}
```

Can you show how to extract only astronomical symbols from `mathabx` isuch as to avoid to overwrite other commands?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323548/conflict-between-mathabx-and-amssymb

Comment: This might also be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570698/82917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mathabx.dcl` we find

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sun}           {0}{mathb}{"40}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mercury}       {0}{mathb}{"41}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Venus}         {0}{mathb}{"42}
        \mathabx@aliases\Venus\girl
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Earth}         {0}{mathb}{"43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mars}          {0}{mathb}{"44}
        \mathabx@aliases\Mars\boy
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Jupiter}       {0}{mathb}{"45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Saturn}        {0}{mathb}{"46}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uranus}        {0}{mathb}{"47}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Neptune}       {0}{mathb}{"48}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pluto}         {0}{mathb}{"49}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varEarth}      {0}{mathb}{"4A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftmoon}      {0}{mathb}{"4B}
        \mathabx@aliases\leftmoon\Moon
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightmoon}     {0}{mathb}{"4C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fullmoon}      {0}{mathb}{"4D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\newmoon}       {0}{mathb}{"4E}
```

OK, now we want to see what `mathb` refers to, which we find in `mathabx.sty`

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
```

Now it's just a matter of refactoring to just use the font as a text one.

```
\documentclass{article}


\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}

\newcommand{\mathbsymbol}[1]{{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Sun}{\mathbsymbol{"40}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Mercury}{\mathbsymbol{"41}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Venus}{\mathbsymbol{"42}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Earth}{\mathbsymbol{"43}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Mars}{\mathbsymbol{"44}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Jupiter}{\mathbsymbol{"45}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Saturn}{\mathbsymbol{"46}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Uranus}{\mathbsymbol{"47}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Neptune}{\mathbsymbol{"48}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Pluto}{\mathbsymbol{"49}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\varEarth}{\mathbsymbol{"4A}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\leftmoon}{\mathbsymbol{"4B}}
\NewCommandCopy{\Moon}{\leftmoon}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rightmoon}{\mathbsymbol{"4C}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\fullmoon}{\mathbsymbol{"4D}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\newmoon}{\mathbsymbol{"4E}}

\begin{document}

\Sun\Mercury\Venus\Earth\Mars\Jupiter\Saturn\Uranus\Neptune\Pluto\Moon

\leftmoon\rightmoon\fullmoon\newmoon

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @egreg, can you show how to modify your code to use the symbols in math mode?
I want to use `$\Sun$` instead of `\Sun`. With the present code, if I type  `$\Sun$` I get the undesiderate symbol `@`.

Comment: @Giuseppe Change into `\newcommand{\mathbsymbol}[1]{\text{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}}}` and, of course, load `amsmath`

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, `mathabx` redefines all math symbols in an undesirable way. You can:
a) change the `mathabx` package with another that does not redefine math symbols and does contain astronomical symbols like `wasysym` or `marvosym` or `starfont` packages
b) keeping `mathabx`package but employ `lualatex` or `xelatex` and loading after `mathabx` package `unicode-math` which will redefine back the math symbols.

Comment: Hi @Miltos P., thank for your answer. I 'd like to keep `mathabx` astronomical symbols. Can you kindly show an example how to extract a single command (e.g. \Sun) and avoid to load the entire package?

Comment: No you can't do that (from what I know). You can use `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` in this case and then load after the `mathabx` the `unicode-math`. Do you want help with that? Have you ever used lualatex or xelatex?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load most of these symbols from Unicode.  Here’s a template that defines the majority of them with the same names, but in text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\varearthfont{Libertinus Serif}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newfontfamily\astrofont{Everson Mono}[Scale=MatchUppercase] % Actually contains U+1F728.

\newcommand\Sun{{\astrofont\symbol{"2609}}}
\newcommand\Mercury{{\astrofont\symbol{"263F}}}
\newcommand\Venus{{\astrofont\symbol{"2640}}}
\newcommand\Earth{{\astrofont\symbol{"1F728}}} % Could instead substitute \oplus.
\newcommand\Mars{{\astrofont\symbol{"2642}}}
\newcommand\Jupiter{{\astrofont\symbol{"2643}}}
\newcommand\Saturn{{\astrofont\symbol{"2644}}}
\newcommand\Uranus{{\astrofont\symbol{"26E2}}}
\newcommand\Neptune{{\astrofont\symbol{"2646}}}
\newcommand\Pluto{{\astrofont\symbol{"2647}}}
\newcommand\varEarth{{\varearthfont\symbol{"2641}}} % Wukipeia thinks this is for a fictitious planet “Proserpina.”
\newcommand\Moon{{\astrofont\symbol{"263D}}}
\newcommand\leftmoon{{\astrofont\symbol{"263D}}}
\newcommand\rightmoon{{\astrofont\symbol{"263E}}}

\begin{document}
The planets: \Mercury\Venus\Earth\varEarth\Mars\Jupiter\Saturn\Uranus\Neptune\Pluto

Other Celestial bodies: \Sun\leftmoon\rightmoon
\end{document}
```

[image: Everson Mono/Libertinus Serif sample]